# nodejs: curly brackets in require statement throwing error

Tags: node.js, express

when I try to start app "sudo start app.js", it throws exception

```
const {notFoundRouteError} = require('../errors');
      ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/project-path/server/index.js:4:25)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
```

Also downgraded node version to **v6.11.0** but it still doesn't work

Comment: Can you please show, how you are exporting the notFoundRouteError from ** errors.js ** file.

Comment: you can start your app via this command    `$ node app.js`

Comment: const constants = require('./../constants');
const {notFoundRouteError} = require('../errors');

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
    const err = new notFoundRouteError(
        constants.ERROR_CODES.UNSUPPORTED_API,
        constants.ERROR_MESSAGES.ROUTE_NOT_FOUND
    );
    return next(err);
};

Comment: I'm going to guess that the script is being run with Node v4, not v6. So you need to provide more context: what OS, what is `start`, how did you install Node originally, how did you downgrade (?) to v6?

Answer (score 0):

Also try `let` instead of `const` like this,

But, you need to enforce the strict mode.

```
"use strict"
let {notFoundRouteError} = require('../errors');
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The parser cannot handle the destructuring assignment, not sure why `let` would solve that.